# How to use constexpr bool instead of preprocessor flag without warnings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constexpr

I tried to use a `constexpr bool` instead of a repeating a pre-processor flag in the following code (simplified):

```
int main()
{
   constexpr bool b
#if SOME_FLAG
         =true;
#else
         =false;
#endif
    bool a=foo(1);
    if (b && a) bar(2);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ear8qYxYY

**The problem** is the line `if (b && a)` where Visual Studio 2019 with warnings enabled (and preprocessor flag not defined) say:

> warning C4127: conditional expression is constant note: consider using 'if constexpr' statement instead

Gcc and Clang seems to accept it.

I know that I can avoid the warning by using `if (a && b)` instead (without generating worse code), but it looks a bit odd.
I also understand that I could write `if constexpr(a) if (b)`, but it would look even weirder and risk problems, and similarly for ignoring or silencing the warning.

Is there a better way to avoid the warning for Visual Studio?

Comment: The compiler is (correctly) complaining that `if (false && a)` is always false.

Comment: I would just disable the warning.

Comment: what is odd about `if (a && b)` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number -  Good question. When changing the code it looks like a weird anti-optimization - but just looking at it in isolation I cannot see any problem. Feel free to add it as answer

Comment: I was just trying to understand what you mean. Actually I still don't get why you called it "odd".

Comment: Also (if `a` is not subsequently needed as a named variable) you could do `if (foo(1) && b) bar(2);`

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
int main()
{
    bool a=foo(1);
#if SOME_FLAG
    if (a) bar(2);
#endif
}
```

?

You can also just disable the warning with a #pragma. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170